# Applying ng-style via ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Probably a noob question but I am a little new to angular.

I am trying to update an ng-style value via an ng-model directive and I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. The goal I am trying to achieve is to have the text within a div align itself via the selections made to the radio buttons.

I posted a fiddle of what I am trying to do below. The base structure of the markup is below. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here?

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="alignmentCtrl">
    <div ng-style="{'text-align': title}">This title should be aligned: {{title}}</div>
    <div class="radio-buttons">
        <input id="left" name="align" type="radio" value="Left" ng-model="title = 'left'">
        <label for="left">Left</label>
        <input id="center" name="align" type="radio" value="Center" ng-model="title = 'center'">
        <label for="center">Center</label>
        <input id="right" name="align" type="radio" value="Right" ng-model="title = 'right'">
        <label for="right">Right</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skooliano/bvnGP/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your jsfiddle.

It's better to set pure JS and no wrap in the "Frameworks & Extensions" and then add the link to angular as an external resources. Then set the body tag with the `ng-app` attribute in "Fiddle Options"

Also you are calling .controller on `app` which is undefined. You should change it to `wdLayout` returned from `angular.module('wdLayout', []);`

```
var wdLayout = angular.module('wdLayout', []);

wdLayout.controller('alignmentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Left";
}]);
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qk53G/